# Hide future months with 0 values from chart in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that automatically pulls in order numbers every month, and a chart to show the trendline. I have formatted the future months because I want the chart to be automatically updated. But the value of the order numbers for future months in currently 0 and that messes with my chart. I want those to be hidden from my chart, so that the chart only runs to the last month.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11FOBKKfxY-usK5aGjrc8KpoiYeMgXrb3apzfYrpoaUg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added a solution in your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11FOBKKfxY-usK5aGjrc8KpoiYeMgXrb3apzfYrpoaUg/edit#gid=1307812569):

you can filter the data first and use those columns as data source for the graph. the formula auto-updates until previous month stats. and also you can just hide those columns since you have the primary A,B columns in visibility.

```
=filter(A:B,EOMONTH(A:A,0)<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))
```

- 

[image]